# how to completely remove rails 4.0.0.rc1 from Linux Mint v14 Nadia

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, linux-mint

I decided to completely remove rails 4.0.0.rc1 and install rails 3.2.13.

I need instructions how to remove rails 4.0.0.rc1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

`gem uninstall rails -v 4.0.0.rc1`

**Update:**

`gem uninstall railties`

or if you already have more version installed:

`gem uninstall railties -v 4.0.0.rc1`

You can check which rails gem installed with `gem list rails`

Of course you can install after your desired gem:

`gem install rails -v 3.2.13`

Comment: I did this. But when I check by rails -v it still shows Rails 4.0.0.rc1. When I did again: gem uninstall rails -v 4.0.0.rc1 it shows: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "rails" is not installed

Comment: I have no idea what exactly happened, when I followed http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/ default rails version become 3.2.13. This is what I wanted...

Comment: Looks, have to uninstall 'railties' gem as well: `gem uninstall railties`

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep on mind this next time and check it out then.

Comment: I tested it this morning, so it is working and good to hear finally your problem solved. We can close this issue now. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! One interesting thing on the web they're many resources how to install rails 4, but now how to remove :) I appreciate your help.

Comment: Kept on getting 4.0.0 as a version number when checking with 'rails -v', but after using the 'railties', it's finally gone!

Answer (score 2):

### If you get the following error:

#### `ERROR: While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError) gem "rails" is not installed`

Enter:
`sudo gem uninstall rails -v 4.0.0`
 Then enter:
`sudo gem uninstall railties`

The command line will prompt you with something similar to this:
`Select gem to uninstall:

 1. railties-3.2.13

 2. railties-4.0.0

 3. All versions`
select the version you want to uninstall by typing the corresponding number. In this case 2.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of the above and what worked for me is slightly different. Here's what I did -

```
tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.6)
actionpack (3.2.6)
activemodel (3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.6)
activeresource (3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.6)
arel (3.0.2)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.5, 1.1.4)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
hoe (3.0.3)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.3)
jquery-rails (2.0.2)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (3.2.0)
multi_json (1.3.6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.2.6)
railties (3.2.6)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rchardet (1.3)
rdoc (3.9.4)
sass (3.1.19)
sass-rails (3.2.5)
sprockets (2.4.3, 2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.15.3)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.5)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)

**tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ which rails**
/usr/bin/rails
tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ ls -l /usr/bin/rails
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 206 Jun 30  2012 /usr/bin/rails
tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ ls -l /usr/bin/rails
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 206 Jun 30  2012 /usr/bin/rails
tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/rails
ruby-railties-3.2: /usr/bin/rails
**tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ sudo apt-get remove ruby-railities-3.2**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby-railities-3.2
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby-railities-3.2'
tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ sudo apt-get remove ruby-railties-3.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  bundler libc-ares2 libev4 libjs-coffeescript libjs-jquery-ui libjs-prototype
  libjs-scriptaculous libv8-3.8.9.20 nodejs rake ruby-actionmailer-3.2
  ruby-actionpack-3.2 ruby-activemodel-3.2 ruby-activerecord-3.2
  ruby-activeresource-3.2 ruby-activesupport-3.2 ruby-arel ruby-blankslate
  ruby-builder ruby-coffee-script ruby-coffee-script-source ruby-dev
  ruby-erubis ruby-execjs ruby-hike ruby-hoe ruby-i18n ruby-journey ruby-mail
  ruby-mime-types ruby-minitest ruby-multi-json ruby-polyglot ruby-rack
  ruby-rack-cache ruby-rack-ssl ruby-rack-test ruby-rchardet ruby-sass
  ruby-sprockets ruby-sqlite3 ruby-text-format ruby-thor ruby-tilt ruby-tmail
  ruby-treetop ruby-tzinfo ruby-uglifier ruby-yajl rubygems-integration
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ruby-coffee-rails ruby-jquery-rails ruby-rails-3.2 ruby-railties-3.2
  ruby-sass-rails
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 223 not upgraded.
After this operation, 1,392 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 173785 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ruby-coffee-rails ...
Removing ruby-jquery-rails ...
Removing ruby-rails-3.2 ...
Removing ruby-sass-rails ...
Removing ruby-railties-3.2 ...

**tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$ gem list**

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.6)
actionpack (3.2.6)
activemodel (3.2.6)
activerecord (3.2.6)
activeresource (3.2.6)
activesupport (3.2.6)
arel (3.0.2)
blankslate (2.1.2.4)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.3.5, 1.1.4)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.3.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
hoe (3.0.3)
i18n (0.6.0)
journey (1.0.3)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.19)
minitest (3.2.0)
multi_json (1.3.6)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.1)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rchardet (1.3)
rdoc (3.9.4)
sass (3.1.19)
sprockets (2.4.3, 2.1.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.6)
thor (0.15.3)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.33)
uglifier (1.2.5)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
tej@ubuntu:~/Rails$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sudo apt purge rails
```